# Finding the integral curves of a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I have been stuck on this question for very long now

Given the vector field
$$
F(x, y) = (5x + 2y, 3x + 7y)
$$
And the ODE system:
$$
x' = 6x + 9y\\
y' = 1x + 4y.
$$
Determine the integral curves to $F$ by finding the general solution to the ODE system.

#### My problem:

I have tried to solve the general solution and got:
$$
v(t) = c(2,-5)e^{-t} + d(5, 2)e^{5t}.
$$
But I don't know how to get the integral curves.

Comment: Hi, you can type mathematics with MathJax, here's some pointers https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you've arrived at the solutions
$$x = ce^{-t} + de^{5t}, \; y = -ce^{-t} + de^{5t}.$$
From here, note that $x+y = 2de^{5t}$ and $x-y = 2ce^{-t}$. For any given solution, $c$ and $d$ are fixed. So we hence have that
$$(x+y)(x-y)^5 = 2d(2c)^5 e^{5t} e^{-5t} = 64c^5d$$
which is constant. So we have integral curves of form
$$(x+y)(x-y)^5 = a,$$
for $a \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: why did you do ```(x+y)(x−y)^5``` ?? :)

Comment: The things that depend on $t$ here are $e^{-t}$ and $e^{5t}$; my solution was essentially just doing algebra to isolate these, and then make them cancel out.

Comment: But why would you want them to cancel out?? :)

Comment: We want them to cancel out so that we can obtain an equation that does not depend on $t$; any equation that doesn't depend on $t$ will only leave $x$ and $y$ and hence be an integral curve.